# simple facebook graph api call not working on live server but working on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents

i am trying to get the number of facebook shares for my website link, using facebook graph api call, for this i have written the below code:

```
  $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.example.com/";
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($content, true);
  if (isset($json["shares"]) && $json["shares"] >= 1) {
     echo "Thanks for sharing";
  } else {
     echo "sorry, you have not yet shared my link.";
  }
```

the above code works perfect on my localhost, but when i tried the same code, it always print me `sorry, you have not yet shared my link`, even when i shared it on facebook.

please help, what i need to do more.. so that it works on live server too..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after doing lots of search i got to know my server does not has `allow_url_fopen = On` so i edited my `php.ini` file.. now it is working perfect...

the `file_get_contents` method requires `allow_url_fopen = On` ....

i have posted this answer so that anyone else looking for this.. may get help..

thanks every one.. who viewed my question..